# jQuery check if body has prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a jQuery function in opencart.
I have several pages with a body class like :
product-category-20
product-category-50
...and so on.

What I've tried :

```
if ($("body").hasClass("common-home, [class*="product-category-"]"){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing double quotes within attribute selector , using `.is()`

```js
$(function() {
  if ($("body").is("[class*=product-category], .common-home")) {
     alert(true)
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body class="product-category-20 product-category-50 common-home"></body>
```